# Is constructing an object within a constructor for another of the same type a good idea?

Tags: c++

Let's take this simplified code sample:

```
class X 
{
 int val;
 public:
  X(int abc):val(abc){}
  X()
  {
    X *b = new X(123);
    val = b->val;
    delete b;
  }
};
```

Is this a good design? Is it an anti-pattern? If so, why?

Note: This is a contrived example. In a more realistic scenario, the constructor is passed the root of the tree and it builds its state based on the left and right child, which is obtained by building objects by passing the children to other constructors.

Comment: As written you have a memory leak, and unless this is a contrived example you've done a bunch of extra work to say `val = 123`.

Comment: You can do this with just one constructor: `X(int abc=123):val(abc){}` (minus the memory leak)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `X b(123); val = b.val;`?

Comment: The example above is not indicative of the work that needs to be done. This is just to get an input on the design.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a good design as you have it presented above. When you're inside the body of the constructor, the object instance for `class X` is already fully constructed at that point. If `X` has members with non-trivial expensive construction, you're only doing extra work by first constructing them and than reassigning new values onto them after the fact. Your example also forces heap allocation during object construction for `X` which is completely unnecessary here.

C++11 offers something called forwarding constructors for achieving this:

```
class X 
{
  int val;
public:
  X(int abc) : val(abc) {}
  X() : X(123) {}
};
```

For C++03 you can refactor your above to just use a default value for the first parameter:

```
class X 
{
  int val;
public:
  X(int abc = 123) : val(abc) {}
};
```

Comment: No, the example is oversimplified. Imagine object X being some function of objects A, B and C.. not just simple parameter allocation.

Comment: Can you add another code example that better captures what you're after?

Comment: @SridharIyer: Still, you'd want a forwarding constructor, so you need only a single place where objects A, B and C are used.

Answer (score 0):

All the calculation done in the first constructor should be in a function. In the second constructor, instead of creating a new object to call the first constructor you would just call this new function that calculate what you want and pass 123.

Note: I haven't coded in C in a long time

```
class X 
{
 int val;
 public:
  X(int abc):val(abc){ val = DoCalculation(123); }
  X()
  {
    val = DoCalculation(123);
  }
};
```